# Formik + yup: how to validate a location schema where the fields(country, state, city) are not mandatory, but if one is filled, each should be filled?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I am having the below schema

```
validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup
    .string()
    .required("Name cannot be empty")
    .matches(NAME_REGEX, "Name can only contain english characters"),
  lastName: yup
    .string()
    .required("Name cannot be empty")
    .matches(NAME_REGEX, "Name can only contain english characters"),
  location: yup
    .object()
    .nullable()
    .shape({
      country: yup.string().required(),
      state: yup.string().required(),
      city: yup.string().required()
    })
})}
```

The validation for `firstName` and `lastName` is working fine but I don't know how to validate the `location`.
**Requirement**: `location` is not at all required to be filled. But if any(`country`/`state`,`city`) of the field is filled, then  all three must be filled. Either all or none.

Though I tried to validate it as above but it's not working.

Another validation requirement is: These values are being selected from the `select` html element, of which the first `<option>` is `<option key={0}>-select-</option>`. So, I don't want my users to select this option as well. As of now, I am handling it in the `onSubmit` by checking the values and if they contain `-select-` then these values will not be considered and will be replaced by the existing ones.

**update**:
`location` can never be null. If the user has not set any of the location field then also `location` would be:

```
location: {
   country: null,
   state: null,
   city: null
}
```

`location` can never be null, only its properties can be.

How should I do these validations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set the default of `location` to null using [mixed.default(value)](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixeddefaultvalue-any-schema) like this:

```
location: yup
    .object()
    .default(null)
    .nullable()
    .shape({
      country: yup.string().required(),
      state: yup.string().required(),
      city: yup.string().required()
    })
```

**Update:**

> location can never be null, only its properties can be.

You can do it like this:

```
location: object()
    .shape({
      country: string().default(null).nullable().test(
        value => value === null || value,
      ),
      state: string().default(null).nullable().test(
        value => value === null || value,
      ),
      city: string().default(null).nullable().test(
        value => value === null || value,
      )
    })
```

Comment: Not working. If I edit `firstname` or `lastName` I am getting error(from formik) `location.country must be a string type, but the final value was: null. If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as .nullable()`. I didn't even touch any of the `select` element

Comment: The `location` object. It can be null but if the user tried to pass it some values(country/state/city), they must pass all three. But with this configuration, even if I edit the `firstName`, yup validates the `location.country`. Why is it going inside the `location`? It should only go inside the `location` if either of country/state/city gets changed.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem, Can you provide a codesandbox? and take a look at https://runkit.com/fraction01/5ccd994faa364f001aaed845 the validation passed successfully

Comment: I think I know where the problem lies. Please see the update.